# How can I handle numbers and strings in input()?

Tags: python, while-loop, try-catch, except

I am new to Python so this is probably a dumb question to many here. I am creating a program that read numbers until the user digit "done". When the user digit "done" the program will visualize total, count and average. If the user doesn't insert a number, then the program must visualize an error message. 
I tried to write the code:

```
while True:
try:
    numbers = input('Enter a number: ')
    if numbers == 'done':
        break

except:
    print ('bad data')
```

For now I have not considered total, count and average. I want to understand how to handle "numbers" and "strings" in input(). Because with my code the error is about "except"

Comment: when you run the code, if you are able to, what is the error you encounter? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60901304/edit) your question adding what you observe is happening. For once, I believe there might be a formatting issue in the code you posted

Comment: Cast it to integer after you have done checking

Answer (score 0):

The String.isnumeric() returns true if your string represents a number. Which allows you to filter your input for numbers.

```
numbers = '123'
numbers.isnumeric()
-> returns true
```

```
numbers = '123asd'
numbers.isnumeric()
-> returns false
```

After you indentified your number you can cast it to a number with

```
float(numbers) // is now of type float (if numbers represents in fact a float)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you. The input()-function returns a string, so in order to calculate with your inputs, you have to convert them to a numeric data type (like int or float). 
If you enter something, which can not be converted to this data type, the except-clause catches the error.

```
sum = 0
count = 0
while True:
    numbers = input('Enter a number: ')
    if numbers == "done":
        break

    try:
        numbers = float(numbers)
        sum += numbers
        count += 1
    except:
        print("bad data, try again.")

# print values after while-loop
print()
print("Total:", sum)
print("You entered", count, "values.")
print("Average:", sum/count)
```